# assembly function to python

Tags: linux, recursion

I have the following function in ASM :

```
//edx=0xe,esi=0,edi=user input
push   %rbx
mov    %edx,%eax
sub    %esi,%eax
mov    %eax,%ebx
shr    $0x1f,%ebx
add    %ebx,%eax
sar    %eax
lea    (%rax,%rsi,1),%ebx
cmp    %edi,%ebx
jle    401013 <func4+0x21>
lea    -0x1(%rbx),%edx
callq  400ff2 <func4>
add    %ebx,%eax
jmp    401023 <func4+0x31>
mov    %ebx,%eax
cmp    %edi,%ebx
jge    401023 <func4+0x31>
lea    0x1(%rbx),%esi
callq  400ff2 <func4>
add    %ebx,%eax
pop    %rbx
retq
```

I tried to convert it into Python:

```
def L1(eax,ebx):
    eax = eax+ebx
    return (eax+ebx)

def L2(eax,ebx,edi,esi,edx):
    eax = ebx
    if (ebx >= edi):
        L1(eax,ebx)
    else:
        esi = esi+1
        eax = func(edi,esi,edx,eax,ebx)
        L1(eax,ebx)

def func(edi,esi,edx,eax,ebx):
    eax = edx
    eax = eax - esi
    ebx = eax
    ebx = ebx >> 31
    eax = eax + ebx
    eax = eax >> 1
    ebx = eax + esi*1
    if (ebx <= edi):
        eax = ebx
        L1(eax,ebx)
    else:
        edx = ebx-1
        eax = func(edi,esi,edx,eax,ebx)
        L1(eax,ebx)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for n in range (2,99):
        result=func(n, 0 , 14,0,0)
        if (result==11):
            print (result)
```

I would really like to know where am I wrong (there are many errors I assume, because it has recursion and many jumps). Many thanks!

Comment: Why would you ever attempt something like this?

Comment: I'm trying to reverse engineer the function

Comment: So.... What isn't working? What do you expect it to do and how exactly does it behave differently?

Comment: Well, I receive "non type" value in eax, I presume it's because I didn't understand the recursion right.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the consensus here.  You have to keep in mind regarding reverse engineering particularly down to the assembly level, Python is an interpreted language so if you were to use something like GDB in Linux, you would have to load the whole interpreter.

You can create a py2exe in Windows for example and use IDA to disassemble it.  I think that might be your best bet!